# How can I set a static IP for juju machines?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, juju

I found a similar question from 2014, [How to give a Juju charm a static ip address - wordpress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507716/how-to-give-a-juju-charm-a-static-ip-address-wordpress/534073#534073), but the answer only says it's not possible, but will be in 15.04, which doesn't help much.

Currently the juju machines are set a IP from DHCP. I would like to set a static IP so that it doesn't change; do I just SSH into the machine and modify the  `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Edit:
I found bionical is using netplan instead of ifupdown, but this "doesn't persist accross instances":
`cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens192:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: <MAC>
            set-name: ens192
```

Is there a way to specify it in the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

modifed `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` (shown below), not sure if this is the right way to do it but communications still work between machines.
`juju status` shows wrong dns entries/public address for a while but eventually updates.

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens192:
            match:
                macaddress: <mac>
            set-name: ens192
            addresses:
              - 192.168.1.10/24
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
                search: [<domain>]
                addresses: [192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3]
```